Game for better teen-sibling relationship
So, as many of other parents on this forum, my two teen sons cannot stop fighting and bothering each other. We have 5 children and the 2 boys are my oldest, 15 and 13 years old.
They get along perfectly with the other siblings (with a fight here and there, but all in the norm). But these two just cannot get along, they fight from the moment they get home from school through any family activity etc.
I am sure this sounds familiar to many people on this forum and I am not proposing that it is something unheard of. But as a parent I want to try and improve it.
I was wondering if there are any board games the two, or the whole family can play that are great for sibling relationship building?

To answer your direct question, I recommend games that put your kids on a team where they work together. This type of game is called co-operative, and some examples well suited for teenagers include:
Board Games:

Pandemic - team up with scientists from around the world to stop a pandemic (this actually came out pre-covid. If you don't think a game about pandemics is right for your family, the creators have a new game called Daybreak which also looks promising)
Hogwarts Battle - for Harry Potter fans, collect cards and build your deck to save Hogwarts
Forbidden Desert - your group of explorers just crashed in a desert - can you work together to survive?
The Crew - You are astronauts on a mission to explore Planet 9 - can you work together and get through the challenges?
Betrayal at the House on the Hill (semi-cooperative) - explore a haunted mansion as a team until one person is revealed to betray the others.

Video Games

Keep Talking and Nobody Explodes - this is available on PC, Nintendo Switch, and a lot of other systems and is honestly one of my all time favorites for building communication and group problem solving skills.
Overcooked 2 - also available on PC, Switch, and bunch of other platforms, loads of fun, very chaotic.

Storytelling Games
I'd also love to mention that table-top roleplaying games (TTRPGs) are really excellent for building teamwork and camaraderie. Dungeons and Dragons is the most well known, but also can be tough to learn. Dungeon World is a more beginner-friendly alternative that's good for this age group all the way to adults. Another option could be a game called Kids on Bikes, which tells stories similar to stranger things and hits well for teens. If you have an adult who is interested in learning more about this and can facilitate, that might be an excellent way to go. Your local library might also have a teen TTRPG group that your boys could join together.
Modifying Games
I just listed a whole lot of games you might buy or borrow, but you could also modify games you already have! Something that often works really well for kids is setting the children against the adults (or even just one adult). If you have board games that the kids already know, think about how you can make this a team challenge for them. For example, in Monopoly, set the rules so that the kids all win if they can make sure you are the first one to go bankrupt. This will encourage them to trade properties between each other and help each other out to force it to happen. I bet you can think of other ways to modify games like Uno, etc. too!
Non-Game Solutions
I'd also recommend that you look more deeply to find out the root of this problem. What is causing them to be at each other's throats so often? If it's possible, doing family therapy with the adults and your two fighting teens might be really beneficial. They're at an age where learning to talk about their problems and communicate proactively when they're upset about something is starting to be possible and important.
